# How can I differentiate between a dynamic obstacle and a static obstacle on local_costmap?

Tags: ros, mobile-robot, ros-noetic, costmap, differential-drive

I'am a starter on ROS. I'am making my own point follower, a robot that follows a "clicked_point" in a map.

So, currently, I'am stopping my robot if anything is too close to it, but I wanted so that it would have more priority to stop for dynamic obstacles (humans, for example) and less priority for walls, so that it can walk closer to them.

Is there a way for me to get this information through some costmap topic?
I'am using ROS noetic.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* defend. I think you can accomplish this by weighting differently whether the objects appear on the [static](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap) or [obstacle](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles) layers. Have you tried this?

Comment: This idea is what I'am trying to do, but I don't know how to get this information from the costmap, do you know how could I do that? Is there a topic that I can get this info from?

Comment: Any thoughts on this? @Chuck